# CX25 ActiveX control in .Net windows service

Tags: c#

I have a CX25 coin dispenser ActiveX provided with test application from client (developed by unknow technology) and need to drive coin dispenser through .Net technology using Win service or API. Successfuly added the COM reference and included the namespace and created the object( See below code reference).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CX25Lib;


namespace CX25HIDUSB
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var cx25 = new CX25();
                Console.WriteLine(cx25.AmountDispensed);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

While accessing "cx25.AmountDispensed" OR any other properties ,got error like "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"

Please it kills my time and looking for real help OR suggestion to handle it in different way  here.

Comment: Any Serial Port Interface constructor like CS25(string PORT) requires the port number and probably a data rate, number bits, and parity.

Comment: This CX25 ActiveX is a USB interface communication , if possible sharing any code reference to achieve it would be really appreciable .

Comment: USB is just anther serial port and still required same as a RS232 serial port.

Comment: Hey @jdweng , i am new to this networking domain. Apart from the above code , i do not see any methods (showing up from intellisense) which accepts port number to connect with. Also the interface constructor is not taking anything(string port ) as parameter .